# Grid View Row Command Event Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having GridView control inside Wizard control, and I am having a linkbutton inside grid, clicking on which will change active index of wizard.
I have three GridViewControls and I am using same Event for RowCommand of these Grids, but its not working, I tried applying breakpoint but its not hitting the break point.
This is my code

```
w ID="GVUsers" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GVUsers_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="GVUsers_RowCommand" 
    OnRowDeleting="GVUsers_RowDeleting" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table">
    <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Crimes" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Username" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Username") %>'></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="gender" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Gender") %>'></asp:Label>                                   
                    <asp:Panel ID="divmsg" runat="server">
                        <asp:LinkButton
                            ID="btnlnkpg18" runat="server" Text="Click here" CommandName="pg18"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:LinkButton ID="delbtn" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you really want to delete?');"
                        CommandName="delete" CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UserId") %>'
                        CssClass="DeleteBtn"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
             <asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

protected void GVUsers_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        var lblgender= e.Row.FindControl("gender") as Label;
        var divlnk=e.Row.FindControl("divmsg") as Panel;

        if(lblgender.Text=="M")         
            divlink.Visible=true;               
        else
            divlink.Visible=false;          
    }
}

protected void GVUsers_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "delete")
    {              
            //Delete
    }

    if (e.CommandName == "pg18")
    {
            Wizard1.ActiveStepIndex = 16;
    }
}
```

I also tried setting CommandName in RowDataBound but no luck, Also the Delete Button is not working.
I am databinding GridView like this

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
//Bind GridView
}
```

Comment: Does your code reaches `GVUsers_RowCommand` event or not?

Comment: I have tried using if(Page.IsPostBack) and binding the Grid, its working fine with it

Answer (score 0):

Syed, try doing this:

1) Rename your RowDataBound event to this:

```
protected void temp()
```

2) Go to the aspx page and delete the RowDataBound property from the gridview.
3) With the gridview still highlighted, click design view.
4) In properties click on 'Events' (the lightning bolt).
4) Double click inside the box for RowDatabound to create the event handler in the .cs
5) With in the RowDatabound inside the .cs add a reference to temp();
6) Add a breakpoint just about the temp() within RowDatabound and run your code.

See if it hits the code, if it does then copy everything from test  into the RowDataBound.

Comment: Can you check that your aspx page is referencing it's code behind at the top like this: CodeBehind="Page.aspx.cs"

Comment: yes I have checked,its referencing, all other events are working